# getting parent/ancestor number from a template

Tags: xslt

I've the below XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<toc-part>
<title><content-style font-style="bold">CHAPTER 1</content-style></title>
<toc-div>
<title><content-style font-style="bold">A</content-style></title>
<toc-item>
<toc-title>Aas v Benham [1891] 2 Ch 244</toc-title>
<toc-pg>160</toc-pg>
</toc-item>
<toc-item>
<toc-title>Aas v Benham [1891] 2 Ch 256</toc-title>
<toc-pg>157</toc-pg>
</toc-item>
</toc-div>
</toc-part>
```

and below XSLT.

```
    <xsl:template match="toc-pg">
        <td class="toc-page">
              <xsl:apply-templates mode="x"/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="x">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+)">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
         <xsl:variable name="prent">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(ancestor::toc-part/toc-subtitle,' ')"/>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:variable name="cha">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$prent"/>
                                </xsl:variable>     <a href="{$prent}">
        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
        </a>

          </xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:non-matching-substring>

          <xsl:analyze-string select="."  regex="http://[^ ]+">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
         <a href="{.}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </a>

          </xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:non-matching-substring>

            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
          </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
```

here i'm trying to get the chapter number as `href`, but here it is throwing me an error. and the error is as below.

```
XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: Error: LRSC_TOC_02.xslt:88: Not a node item - item has type xs:string with value '160' -   Details: -     XPTY0020: The context item in an axis step must be a node
```

please let me know how to avoid this error and retrieve the chapter number.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside `<xsl:matching-substring>` the context item is the matching substring itself, so of you want to navigate the tree from the node that was the context outside `analyze-string` then you need to save that in a variable at the start of the template:

```
<xsl:variable name="dot" select="."/>
```

and then use

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after($dot/ancestor::toc-part/toc-subtitle,' ')"/>
```

(or just do the whole `substring-after(ancestor::toc-part/toc-subtitle, ' ')` outside `analyze-string` and save *that* in a variable)

Comment: Hi @IanRoberts, i've applied this, but the value pulled is null.

Comment: @user2423959 there aren't actually any toc-subtitle elements in your example XML, did you mean `title` instead?